# STRING_SPLIT logic fails to me

Tags: sql

I have a table like below

```
id   value  relation
x     1      x,y,z
y     2      null
z     3      null
k     4      null
```

I have tried like below

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT value
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(relation, ',')
)
```

My expected output:

```
    id   value  relation
    x     1      x,y,z
    y     2      null
    z     3      null
```

But my current output is:

```
    id   value  relation
    x     1      x,y,z
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: @FilipKováč Nope.  `IN` does ***not*** look inside comma separated strings in that way.  Unless you use something to split that value up, it's not a list, it's a single string.  `'x' IN ('x,y,z')` is `FALSE` only after spliting it up does it work `'x' IN ('x', 'y', 'z')` *(with **three** separate strings)* is `TRUE`.  If you're convinced it does work as you described, make a demo on http://dbfiddle.uk and prove it.

Comment: @MatBailie yeah you are right, i wrote some framework to do it for me back in the day, and it is working in code with numbers, not chars. I am sorry for wrong info.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code compares each row's `id` the the values in `relation` ***in the same row***.

You can accomplish your desired results this with a `join`, which will compare each rows `id` to every other row's `relation` list...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table   AS rels
INNER JOIN
  table   AS vals
    ON vals.id IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(rels.relation, ','))
```

Or, if you ***know*** that you'll only ever have ***one*** value in the relation column, you can use a sub-query to find that single value to pass in to the `STRING_SPLIT()`

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table
WHERE
  id IN (SELECT value
           FROM STRING_SPLIT(
                  (SELECT MAX(relation) FROM table),
                  ','
                )
        )
```

Jumping through these hoops may also suggest to you that your data structure isn't SQL friendly.

As a principle, storing multiple values as a single comma separated string is a bad idea, and you should look at concepts such as junction tables or link tables for assocating many values to a single row.

Comment: first query  return like below id value relation x 1 x,y,z x 1 x 1

Comment: second one perfect for me .

Comment: @xyz - Just change the `SELECT *` to return the specific colums that you need.  That's a very basic part of SQL, it's like me having to explain the different between `+` and `-` in maths...  `SELECT vals.id, vals.value, vals.relation` will give just three columns instead of six...